# Handling Application File Genearation

Tags: c++, installation, architecture, windows-installer, software-design

Say I have a C++ application BuildHouse that generates custom House applications

**BuildHouse:** (Application directory; what the User would Install as a product)

> - BuildHouse.exe, etc.
> - (Input) User inputs data, configures settings
> - (Output) Generates a House

**UserHouse:** (Small user-generated application directory)

> - Specified Path
> - Supporting Files (Many)
> - Core Files (Few)
> - House.exe (Reliant on the above)

**Notes:**

- UserHouse contains Core Files that are dynamically generated by BuildHouse.exe, the Supporting Files are simply copies that would be some part of the BuildHouse.exe installation.
- I have never developed software complete with an installer, and have been looking at things such as https://wixtoolset.org.
- Using C++ with CMake targeted for Windows(10)

**Current Solution:**

- Use C++17's Filesystem Library to generate House directories, write and path Core files, copy over Support files from the Housebuilder directory

**Question:**

Exactly **WHAT** would handle the **Supporting Files** for each house generated? Should they simply sit in the directory of the BuildHouse installation, waiting to be copied for each House generated? Is there some type of package format I should store them in? Should I have something that writes them each time?

> To clarify my mentioning of WiX: I am planning to use it to install
> the HouseBuild software nonetheless, but am just asking if it would
> have functionality to solve this issue.

I am completely inexperienced in installation development, thus lack the proper technical words to explain this specific question. Any mentions or explanations of the processes surrounding this circumstance are appreciated.

Comment: Voting to close as this is opinion based. You basically have to choose between using the files directly from the BuildHouse directory (and risk "effects at a distance" should BuildHouse ever be updated) OR copy the files when you generate UserHouse (and waste an unknown amount of disk space). Go with option 2 in absence of more information.

Comment: @Botje so the best solutions are as simple as my initial attempt, just storing the files in the installation directory and copying them over whenever a new House is built? I imagined much more advanced solutions were the norm, and I was just ignorant. If any more points of information could be useful let me know.